# Leitura de arquivo e contar elementos repetidos

Tags: python, arquivo

Olá, pessoal.
Preciso de uma ajuda para resolver um pepino de forma rápida.
No trabalho tenho um arquivo que possui 18 caracteres por linha (são mais de 600 linhas). Preciso ler cada linha e em cada linha ler 6 caracteres por vez. E nesses 6 caracteres quero contar quantas vezes ele se repete nesse arquivo. Ex: ABCDEF - 4, ABDEDF - 1, AAAAAA - 10...
Estava pesquisando que Python poderia ser a minha solução (se alguém tiver uma bala de prata com outras linguagem é bem vinda).
Desculpem-me não dominar programação para já deixar algo q eu comecei. Mas vi que posso usar algo parecido com isso (Python):

```
from collections import Counter

with open('arq.txt') as f:
    ocorrencias = Counter(f.read().split())
print(ocorrencias)
```

Comment: Você já tentou usar _slices_ de strings? Pesquise sobre isso, talvez te ajude. :)

Comment: Eu teria que fazer um for pegando o interator e interator + 6 como indexadores?

Comment: https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/FrequentStimulatingLocatorprogram#main.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para futuras pesquisas do tipo.

```
import json
import textwrap
from collections import Counter

group_size = 6
res = Counter()

with open('arq.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    res.update({_: 1 for _ in textwrap.wrap(line, group_size)})

print(res)    
with open('saida.json', 'w') as f: #saída gravada em json
  json.dump(dict(res), f)
```